# Open sets in the spectrum of a Dedekind domain are affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

I'm trying to prove the following statement: All open sets in the spectrum $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ of a Dedekind domain $A$ are affine. Since all open sets are cofinite, my idea is to prove that an open set of the form $X-\mathfrak{p}$ is affine, and then use induction.

I've found this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174210/the-prime-spectrum-of-a-dedekind-domain), which explains the condition for all open sets to be principal. In particular, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is of finite order in the ideal class group, then $\mathfrak{p}^n=(f)$, $X-\mathfrak{p}=D_f$ is principal; if however $\mathfrak{p}$ is of infinite order, then $X-\mathfrak{p}$ is not principal. In this latter case, what is the coordinate ring? And how to prove that it is affine?

Thanks.

Comment: If $\mathfrak p = (f,g)$, the coordinate ring of $U := X - \mathfrak p = D_f \cup D_g$ is $\mathcal O_X(U) = A_f \cap A_g$

Comment: Thanks. But then how to prove that $X-\mathfrak{p}$ is affine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I = (f,g)$ be an ideal of $A$ and let $U = X - V(I)$. Then it is pretty easy to see that $f,g \in A \subset \mathcal O_X(U) = \mathcal O_U(U) = A_f \cap A_g =: B$ satisfy the conditions of Exercise II.2.17 in Hartshorne:

1) $(f,g)B=B$, because you can check this locally and locally its certainly true.

2) $U_f$ and $U_g$ are affine, because they are equal to $D(f)$ and $D(g)$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you! This explains the case $X-\mathfrak{p}$. However I'm lost again because the induction won't work unless we prove that $B$ is still a Dedekind domain. Or is there a direct proof of the statement?

Comment: Obviously, I have worked with an arbitrary ideal $I$, so I have covered all cases.

Comment: But since you asked: $B$ is again a Dedekind domain, because $\operatorname{Spec} B=U$ is a notherian regular integral scheme of dimension one, hence $B$ is a noetherian regular integral domain of dimension one.

Comment: This is revelant for the proof: [In a Dedekind domain every ideal is either principal or generated by two elements.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597543/in-a-dedekind-domain-every-ideal-is-either-principal-or-generated-by-two-element)